# Can't get raise Return to work when using coroutines

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, coroutine

I've been experimenting with Python 2.7 and Tornado 3.2. I've been trying to get a simple coroutine example to work, but without much luck:

```
import tornado.web
from tornado.gen import coroutine
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.gen import Return

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    # Tried with and without @asynchronous
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
            data = MainService().get_google_data() 
            self.write(data)


class MainService:

    @coroutine
    def get_google_data(self):
            response = yield AsyncHTTPClient().fetch("http://www.google.com")
            raise Return(value = 'hello')
```

I expected this would write out 'hello' when cURLing the URL. Instead, I get:

```
...
File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 656, in write
raise TypeError("write() only accepts bytes, unicode, and dict objects")
TypeError: write() only accepts bytes, unicode, and dict objects
```

Apparently, a Future is being returned, but calling `result()` on the future throws another exception: `DummyFuture does not support blocking for results`

The Tornado docs say that in order to return a value from a coroutine, you raise a Return exception. Looking at the source code, that indeed seems to be what's expected. Yet, when I run it, it doesn't seem to work.

Appreciate any insights on this!

Comment: Digging deeper into Runner.run(), I feel I might have jumped to conclusions on what that does.

Comment: As an aside, you can just `raise Return('hello')`. No need for the `value=`.

Comment: @dano Yeah, the value = was just there for no good reason. Digging into Runner, I see now that it doesn't quite do what I thought it did at first glance. It returns a future, which is what I think you were saying in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `yield` the call to `get_google_data()`:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        data = yield MainService().get_google_data() 
        self.write(data)
```

Tornado coroutines always return a `Future`. You wait for the result of that `Future` by calling `yield` on it. Without the `yield`, you just end up getting the `Future` back immediately, without waiting for the coroutine to complete. You should also use the `@coroutine` decorator on the `get` method, in addition to `get_google_data`. The `@asynchronous` decorator is generally used if you want to use callbacks, rather than coroutines.

Comment: Yup, this makes sense. So if I have a handler that calls a service that calls a data access object, and the data access object implements a coroutine, all the calls all the way up the stack need to yield and be decorated with coroutines?

Comment: @MrSilverSnorkel Yep, coroutines are "viral", generally. Once you add one, everything that calls it wants to become one, too. There are ways of calling a coroutine without actually having the calling context also be a coroutine, but its a little bit clunkier than just "yield coroutine_call()`.

Comment: thanks, you've given me food for thought. Could you point me at an example of one of these ways to call a coroutine without having the calling context be a coroutine?

Comment: @MrSilverSnorkel The second and third examples [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html#examples) show two ways of calling the coroutine `http_client.fetch()` from non-coroutine methods. The second uses a pure callbacks, the third uses a callback attached to the `Future`.